# Create a dynamic table in a PDF Form programmatically

Tags: forms, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I need to generate a pdf based on a template form.
In that form there is a table that needs to be populated.

Since the table can have a unknown amount of rows, what I was thinking was drawing the table and then adding it to a space on the form.
As in, the form would have a acrofield to receive the table itself.

I already managed to create the table and put it inside a pdf, but I'm having issues puting that table into a acrofield.

As far as I can understand a form only appears to accept these: button, text, choice, or signature.

I'm using Apache pdfbox and [easyTable](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable) to manipulate the form and create the table.

Is it possible what I want to do? If so, where can I find more information about this topic?

Edit: [This answer](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/dynamic-table-q16555.aspx) seems to be what I want to do.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to dump a table into a position on the pdf.
Now the question is more, is it possible to move or resize a existing field on the pdf and reflow the text to acomodate the table size?

Comment: You cannot (or should not) put the table into an actual AcroForm field. What you can do, though, is to take only the position and dimensions of the AcroForm field and add your table right there in the regular page content.

Comment: *"is it possible to move or resize a existing field on the pdf and reflow the text to acomodate the table size?"* - This is difficult, in particular if your template can contain watermarks/background graphics, or headers and footers, or vertically overlapping fields.

Comment: There are tools for this specific purpose. How this is done is that you add a table to you template and specify the table row as repeating row. When the engine populates the data to generate the PDF, it iterates over all your data that you specify and creates extra row for the data entry. You can have a look at iText DITO which is based on HTML5 or any other tool like Docmosis based on Word document. Note that final PDF is not a PDF Form anymore. It is a document that contains all your data. Note: I am working at iText.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using IText acroforms?. We have lots of existing templates and we don't want to use iText DITO as we would have to recreate all the templates. XFA is not an option as it is an old technology and deprecated.